# Is there any benefits at all to use dispatch_once pattern with primitives?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dispatch

Which is better?

```
static unsigned unitFlags;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
});
```

OR is that just as efficient as writing

```
unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
```

Or is there some other patterns more efficient? Would a define be better for 'unitFlags'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just do:

```
static unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
```

You only need to do the `dispatch_once` trick if the expression on the right isn't a valid compile-time constant. But this is a valid compile-time constant, so you don't have to go through that slight of hand.

But the `static` expression is generally better than a `#define` (it's typed, and for some complicated expressions, it can be more efficient). Stick with the `static`, in my opinion.

Comment: Ok. So if I understand you right: The result of the bits are just computed once at compiletime? Or is it first time at runtime? Anyways only once?

Comment: @hfossli Yes, compile-time and only once. If the expression is sufficiently complicated that it can't be done at compile-time, you'll get a compiler error that tells you that.

Comment: That's great! And that's even if it is inline in a function?

Comment: Just try it. The compiler will tell you whether it can deal with it as a compile-time `static` assignment or not.